# Digital clock with date

Tags: android, system-clock

I want to show date and time. I have used digital clock for time. its perfectly fine. But how to show date with the clock? so if date is changed in real then in my page date is also updated? I have used digital clock for time.

```
<DigitalClock
            android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DigitalClock" />
```

Comment: Have you found an way to show digital clock with date.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android [TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) instead of DigitalClock